# Direct X 11 Problems

Tags: parsing, model, loading, directx-11, .obj

So I am making a game engine in DX11 and this is a strange problem I have been having for a while.

http://gfycat.com/MerryLikableGreyhounddog

I thought it was the back facing normals but that doesn't make a difference.
I tried the culling modes. No luck

The thing to look at in the .gif is the pin for the grenade. Notice how it isnt half invisible at all times but only when it is on the camera side of the grenade.

I'll post some code. Please ask if you would like to see anymore.

This is the function that loads the data from the .obj file.

```
bool CModel::LoadModel(char* filename)
{
struct Coord
{
    float x, y, z;
};

struct UV
{
    float u, v;
};

struct Face
{
    int v1, t1, n1;
    int v2, t2, n2;
    int v3, t3, n3;
};

//Check to see if the file exists
bool result = CheckFile(filename);
if(!result) return false;

std::ifstream file;

char line, slash;

Coord*  vertex  = new Coord[m_VertexCount];
UV*     uvs     = new UV[m_TextureCount];
Coord*  normals = new Coord[m_NormalCount];
Face*   face    = new Face[m_FaceCount];

m_VertexCount = m_TextureCount = m_NormalCount = m_FaceCount = 0;

file.open(filename);

//Read in the file
file.get(line);
while(!file.eof())
{
    if(line == 'v')
    {
        file.get(line);

        //Data is describing the vertex coordinates
        if(line == ' ')
        {
            file>>vertex[m_VertexCount].x>>vertex[m_VertexCount].y>>vertex[m_VertexCount].z;

            //Invert z axis
            vertex[m_VertexCount].z = vertex[m_VertexCount].z * -1.0f;
            m_VertexCount++;
        }

        //Data is describing the UV coordinates
        if(line == 't')
        {
            file>>uvs[m_TextureCount].u>>uvs[m_TextureCount].v;

            //Invert y axis
            uvs[m_TextureCount].v = 1.0f - uvs[m_TextureCount].v;
            m_TextureCount++;
        }

        //Data is describing the normal coordinates
        if(line == 'n')
        {
            file>>normals[m_NormalCount].x>>normals[m_NormalCount].y>>normals[m_NormalCount].z;

            //Invert z axis
            normals[m_NormalCount].z = normals[m_NormalCount].z * -1.0f;
            m_NormalCount++;
        }
    }

    //Data is describing the face coordinates
    if(line == 'f')
    {
        file.get(line);
        if(line == ' ')
        {
            file>>face[m_FaceCount].v3>>slash>>face[m_FaceCount].t3>>slash>>face[m_FaceCount].n3
                >>face[m_FaceCount].v2>>slash>>face[m_FaceCount].t2>>slash>>face[m_FaceCount].n2
                >>face[m_FaceCount].v1>>slash>>face[m_FaceCount].t1>>slash>>face[m_FaceCount].n1;
            m_FaceCount++;
        }
    }

    //Read rest of line
    while(line != '\n')
        file.get(line);

    //Next line
    file.get(line);
}
file.close();

//Put data into model structure
int vIndex, tIndex, nIndex = 0;

std::ofstream fout;
fout.open("model.txt");
//Finally put all the data into the model
//Since the faces are stored in threes it gets pretty messy
fout<<"Vertex Count : "<<m_FaceCount*3<<std::endl;

for(int i=0; i<m_FaceCount; i++)
{
    vIndex = face[i].v1 - 1;
    tIndex = face[i].t1 - 1;
    nIndex = face[i].n1 - 1;

    fout<< vertex[vIndex].x << ' ' << vertex[vIndex].y << ' ' << vertex[vIndex].z << ' '
        << uvs[tIndex].u << ' ' << uvs[tIndex].v << ' '
        << normals[nIndex].x << ' ' << normals[nIndex].y << ' ' << normals[nIndex].z << std::endl;

    vIndex = face[i].v2 - 1;
    tIndex = face[i].t2 - 1;
    nIndex = face[i].n2 - 1;

    fout<< vertex[vIndex].x << ' ' << vertex[vIndex].y << ' ' << vertex[vIndex].z << ' '
        << uvs[tIndex].u << ' ' << uvs[tIndex].v << ' '
        << normals[nIndex].x << ' ' << normals[nIndex].y << ' ' << normals[nIndex].z << std::endl;

    vIndex = face[i].v3 - 1;
    tIndex = face[i].t3 - 1;
    nIndex = face[i].n3 - 1;

    fout<< vertex[vIndex].x << ' ' << vertex[vIndex].y << ' ' << vertex[vIndex].z << ' '
        << uvs[tIndex].u << ' ' << uvs[tIndex].v << ' '
        << normals[nIndex].x << ' ' << normals[nIndex].y << ' ' << normals[nIndex].z << std::endl;
}
```

Depth Buffer Code:

```
//Initialise the depth buffer description
ZeroMemory(&depthBufferDesc, sizeof(depthBufferDesc));

depthBufferDesc.Width = width;
depthBufferDesc.Height = height;
depthBufferDesc.MipLevels = 1;
depthBufferDesc.ArraySize = 1;
depthBufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_D24_UNORM_S8_UINT;
depthBufferDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
depthBufferDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
depthBufferDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
depthBufferDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_DEPTH_STENCIL;
depthBufferDesc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
depthBufferDesc.MiscFlags = 0;

//Create texture for the depth buffer
result = m_Device->CreateTexture2D(&depthBufferDesc, NULL, &m_DepthStencilBuffer);
if(FAILED(result)) return false;

//Initialise the stencil state description
ZeroMemory(&depthStencilDesc, sizeof(depthStencilDesc));

depthStencilDesc.DepthEnable = true;
depthStencilDesc.DepthWriteMask = D3D11_DEPTH_WRITE_MASK_ALL;
depthStencilDesc.DepthFunc = D3D11_COMPARISON_LESS;

depthStencilDesc.StencilEnable = true;
depthStencilDesc.StencilReadMask = 0xFF;
depthStencilDesc.StencilWriteMask = 0xFF;

//Operations if pixel is front-facing.
depthStencilDesc.FrontFace.StencilFailOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
depthStencilDesc.FrontFace.StencilDepthFailOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_INCR;
depthStencilDesc.FrontFace.StencilPassOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
depthStencilDesc.FrontFace.StencilFunc = D3D11_COMPARISON_ALWAYS;

//Operations if pixel is back-facing.
depthStencilDesc.BackFace.StencilFailOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
depthStencilDesc.BackFace.StencilDepthFailOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_DECR;
depthStencilDesc.BackFace.StencilPassOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
depthStencilDesc.BackFace.StencilFunc = D3D11_COMPARISON_ALWAYS;

//Create  depth stencil state
result = m_Device->CreateDepthStencilState(&depthStencilDesc, &m_DepthStencilState);
if(FAILED(result)) return false;

//Set depth stencil state
m_DeviceContext->OMSetDepthStencilState(m_DepthStencilState, 1);

//Initailse the depth stencil view.
ZeroMemory(&depthStencilViewDesc, sizeof(depthStencilViewDesc));

//Set up depth stencil view description.
depthStencilViewDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_D24_UNORM_S8_UINT;
depthStencilViewDesc.ViewDimension = D3D11_DSV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
depthStencilViewDesc.Texture2D.MipSlice = 0;

//Create the depth stencil view.
result = m_Device->CreateDepthStencilView(m_DepthStencilBuffer, &depthStencilViewDesc, &m_DepthStencilView);
if(FAILED(result)) return false;

//Bind render target view and depth stencil buffer to render pipeline
m_DeviceContext->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &m_RenderTargetView, m_DepthStencilView);
```

Raster State Code:

```
//Setup the raster description
rasterDesc.AntialiasedLineEnable = false;
rasterDesc.CullMode = D3D11_CULL_BACK;
rasterDesc.DepthBias = 0;
rasterDesc.DepthBiasClamp = 0.0f;
rasterDesc.DepthClipEnable = true;
rasterDesc.FillMode = D3D11_FILL_SOLID;
rasterDesc.FrontCounterClockwise = false;
rasterDesc.MultisampleEnable = false;
rasterDesc.ScissorEnable = false;
rasterDesc.SlopeScaledDepthBias = 0.0f;

//Create the rasterizer state
result = m_Device->CreateRasterizerState(&rasterDesc, &m_RasterState);
if(FAILED(result)) return false;

//Set the rasterizer state.
m_DeviceContext->RSSetState(m_RasterState);
```

Comment: There are a number of things that could be wrong. For example, do you have a depth buffer set correctly? Also, take a look at [DirectX Tool Kit](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=248929) which includes code for loading from various runtime mesh formats, and [DirectXMesh](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=324981) which has code for converting Wavefront OBJ to those runtime formats.

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn I have set up the depth buffer correctly to my knowledge. I have updated to show the depth buffer code

Comment: Can you paste your RasterState code too, as it really doesn't look like that's setup right?

Comment: @AdamMiles Added the rasterstate code.

Comment: What happens when you change `CullMode` to `D3D11_CULL_FRONT`? What happens when you change `FrontCounterClockwise` to `true`?

Comment: @rashmatash This is with cull front: http://i.imgur.com/x3tK2BL.png
This is with both: http://i.imgur.com/cwaket6.png
This is FrontCounterClockwise: http://i.imgur.com/x3Fp6oB.png

Comment: I think one of those black pictures (or both) is ok, but you have to set the direction of your light source correctly ;)

Comment: @rashmatash Well I'm using a directional light, so position has nothing to do with it.
Also changing the shader to a texture shader (no light) shows that the problem isnt solved and made worse

Comment: Oh that's a bummer. I didn't say anything about light position though ;) good luck!

Comment: @rashmatash lol, sorry. I've sent an email to my lecturer so hopfully he will be able to help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am very stupid.
When I was initialising the D3D device I accidentally set the near clip distance as the far clip and vice versa so everything was being rendered back to front.

Remember kids always check what you are passing to functions!